# Infinite date scroll - WebSql JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, database, date, web-sql

Is there a built in method for infinite date scrolling?

I am making a database program, and the point is to display data added over especific dates. 
Of course I can't do this forever in time:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date >="2013-04-01" AND date <"2013-05-01
```

Plus, the month days change every year. You guys have an idea of how should I implement my code to adjust into the dates?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by infinite scrolling, but if you're displaying data based on a date range, just pass the date parameters from the UI to the query.  If you are displaying 1 month of data at a time, then the user could use Previous / Next button to 'scroll' through time.  Or you could let them pick any two dates and see whatever range they need to look at.